# Number of possible solutions in modular equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have given the result value $z$. I know that 
$$z \equiv x\cdot(x-1)\pmod p$$
where $p$ is prime and the value $p$ is fixed and given. I have also given the information, that $x \in \{m, M\}$, where $m, M \in \mathbb Z_p$. From this equation I want to compute value $x$.
Can I figure how many possible values of $x$ satisfy the given equation? Does this number of possible values depends on value $p$?

Answer (score 2):

[From Lagrange's theorem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auryzn5rlbz5lan/Lagrange_Theorem_NT.pdf?dl=0), there can be at most two solutions.

Note that
$$4z \equiv 4x^2-4x \pmod{p} \implies 4z+1 \equiv (2x-1)^2\pmod{p}$$
Hence, for a solution to exist, $4z+1$ must be a quadratic residue.

- If $4z+1$ is not a quadratic residue, then there is no solution.
- If $4z+1$ is zero, then there is only one solution, namely,
  $$(2x-1)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \implies (2x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \implies x = \dfrac{p+1}2\pmod{p}$$
- If $4z+1$ is a non-zero quadratic residue, i.e., $a^2 \equiv (4z+1) \pmod{p}$, then there are two solution, namely
  \begin{align}
  (2x-1)^2 \equiv a^2 \pmod{p} \implies (2x-1+a)(2x-1-a) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}\\ (2x-1+a)(2x-1-a) \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \implies x \equiv \dfrac{1\pm a}2\pmod{p}
  \end{align}

Comment: If $4z+1\equiv 0\pmod p$ then there is only one solution.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer! It's very helpful. However I have only one question -Do I think correctly, that if we wouldn't know that $x \in {m,M}$ where $m, M \in Z_p$ should the answer for only one solution be $x = \frac{l\cdot p + 1}{2}$, for some integer $l$?